How can i sync two different apps to use Firebase Cloud Messaging through GetStream.io?
so i'm building a E hailing app that involves a rider app and a driver app, two separate apps.
so as you can imagine
the first one has a package name of com.roundtripz
the second one: com.roundtripzdriver
now, I'm trying to implement Firebase cloud messaging for notifications, i'm using Getstream.io for this.
but the problem i'm having is, i tried creating two firebase apps, one for each,  which means they both have different google-services.json files. but trying to send a message from one to the the other doesn't work.
I have also tried using the roundtripz google-service.json file for the roundtripzdriver app, when i try to send a test message from getstream dashboard, it says ID Mismatch
After using the roundtripz google-service.json file in my android/app/ folder, now the app won't even compile anymore. My error is given below
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.roundtripzdriver'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.roundtripzdriver'

* Try:

Any help would be greatly appreciated right now, thanks.
